# Spring Kafka and Kafka Streams

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

In Spring Boot application I'm trying to configure Kafka Streams. With plain Kafka topics, everything is working fine, but I unable to get working Spring Kafka Streams.

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public StreamsConfig kStreamsConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "testStreams");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Integer().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
        return new StreamsConfig(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {

        KStream<String, String> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("post.sent");

        stream.mapValues(post -> post.toString()).to("streamingTopic2");

        stream.print();

        return stream;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic kafkaTopicTest() {
        return new NewTopic("streamingTopic2", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "streamingTopic2", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void testListener(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {

        String value = consumerRecord.value();

        System.out.println("VALUE: " + value);

        ack.acknowledge();
    }

}
```

I want to create a stream based on `post.sent` topic. To apply a simple transformation and to send the messages from this stream to test `streamingTopic2` topic.

Right now when I send the message into `post.sent` topic I unable immediately to get it in "streamingTopic2" but after my application restart it start fails with the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition streamingTopic2-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[123, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 53, 98, 56, 49, 53, 99, 97, 51, 52, 102, 97, 101, 102, 48, 52, 55, 97, 52, 48, 48, 100, 52, 50, 97, 34, 44, 34, 115, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 34, 58, 34, 83, 69, 78, 84, 34, 44, 34, 101, 120, 116, 101, 114, 110, 97, 108, 80, 111, 115, 116, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 48, 53, 54, 97, 57, 51, 49, 101, 45, 56, 97, 53, 100, 45, 52, 100, 52, 52, 45, 97, 101, 50, 48, 45, 53, 99, 51, 53, 52, 56, 57, 52, 98, 97, 53, 49, 34, 44, 34, 99, 104, 97, 116, 78]] from topic [streamingTopic2]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"id":"5b815ca34faef047a400d42a","status":"SENT","externalPostId":"056a931e-8a5d-4d44-ae20-5c354894ba51","chatName":.......":"[truncated 626 bytes]; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1138) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1092) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:10) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1611) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1234) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:248) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:224) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:967) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3300(Fetcher.java:93) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1144) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:993) ~[kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clien
```

To `post.sent` I send the following messages `<String, Post>` where the `Post` is my own complex type but I don't know right now how to translate it to `<String, String>` in `kStream()` in order to be able to consume it in `testListener()`.

Please suggest how to make it work.

Comment: According to the stacktrace, you've set JsonDeserializer somewhere, but that isn't in the code you've shown... If you want to make a Post into a String, you can use `map` action on a stream

Comment: Thanks, could you please show the example of how to properly use `map` for this case?

Comment: Well, Assuming you had `KStream<Object, Post> stream`, then `stream.mapValues(post -> post.toString())` https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations

Comment: Unfortunately the same error

Comment: Where are you setting the JSON deserializer? It won't work for raw strings until you change that

Comment: I use the following `return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));` in order to define the `consumerFactory` bean

Comment: What happens when you use String Deserializer for both the key and value?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember the purpose of this serializer right now.. it was introduced 1 year ago. I'm testing the system right now in order to avoid using this serializer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is working now with `StringDeserializer` but  I able to receive the message into `testListener()` only after application restart.  How to receive the messages from the Stream immediately with no needs to restart the app?

Comment: It should be actively consuming while the app is running... I don't think a restart is needed. Are you actively producing into the topic?

Comment: no, I did just a single message for test

Comment: Okay, so if you run the app once, then the message is consumed, and the consumer group offset is moved forward, past that message. You either need to use a different group id, or reset the group offsets if you would like to continue reading the one message again and again

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the one more dumb question but it is not clear to me about the contract between Stream and Topic. I thought the message was consumed by Stream but then delivered to Topic. Do they use the same offset?

Comment: A Stream is backed by a topic. When you write a client that consumes from a topic using any API, it'll commit the marker of what has already been consumed back into a separate topic. That way, if your app fails, for example, or you simply restart it manually, it knows where to resume from without going back to the beginning.

Comment: I have the following sequence - some logic in my application sends the message into `post.sent` topic. This topic is the source for `kStream` - `kStreamBuilder.stream("post.sent")`. After some transformation in `kStream` it sends the message to `streamingTopic2` topic - `stream.mapValues(post -> post.toString()).to("streamingTopic2");` . Nothing fails on the application level but `testListener()` (the listener for `streamingTopic2` ) only receives the message on the next application start. Unfortunately, I still don't understand why...

Comment: I would start your streams app, then start a consumer on the destination topic, and then start a producer on the source topic. Then you should see events flowing. Otherwise, you might want to open a separate post as I've answered the initial error

Comment: I moved to Confluent Platform and the issue is gone. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your usage of

> `return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));` in order to define the `consumerFactory` bean

Well, I can't say how you have Produced data into the topic, but the JSON parser is failing.

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"id":"5b815ca34faef047a400d42a","status":"SENT","externalPostId":"056a931e-8a5d-4d44-ae20-5c354894ba51","chatName":.......":"[truncated 626 bytes]; line: 1, column: 1]
...
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize
```

Based on `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[123, 34, 105 ...`, I would say you have at some point done a `byte[]` producer, rather than explicitly defined using `StringSerializer` or `JSONSerializer` during production.

You could get around your error by using `new StringDeserializer()` or even do no conversion at all with `ByteArrayDeserializer` in your `consumerFactory`, but then you'll still need to handle how to later parse that event into a object that you want to manipulate and extract fields from.

Answer (score 2):

To use Streams you need to do something like this:

```
@EnableBinding(MyStreamProcessor.class)

@StreamListener
    public void process(@Input("input") KTable<String,MyMessage> myMessages,
                        @Input("streammapping") KTable<String, StreamMapping> streamMessages) {
    ...
    }

interface MyStreamProcessor {
@Input("input")
KTable<?, ?> input();

@Input("streammapping")
KTable <?, ?> streamMapping();
```

}

and then put your processing code in the method body. KStreams work the same way